# How to define custom character with code > 126 using ESC/POS commands?

Tags: escpos

I'm trying to define custom characters on thermal printer NCR 7199.
I used ESC/POS command

```
ESC & y c1 c2 x d1...dn
```

and it works fine. But this command can change only characters in range 32-126, and those characters are latin letters and common symbols.

I'd prefer to replace characters with codes 8E-8F, for example, but cannot do it using this command.

Is it possible? Or is there any other ESC/POS command for user-defined characters?

UPD.
It seems like a firmware update can fix this problem. Firmware version on our printer is v99.21, and I saw this in release notes:

```
v99.25 "based on v99.24"
1. Allowed User-defined characters defined range from 20H to FFH in 7199 Emulation mode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating firmware.

After updating "Main Firmware" to v99.27 (it seems that version must be greater or equal v99.25) and changing Emulation mode to "NCR 7199" I was finally able to define characters in all range 20-FF.

Answer (score 0):

Another user-defined character setting command for Kanji is for printers that support the MBCS character set, which is not what you want.

[FS 2](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=178)

> Define user-defined Kanji characters

However, although it is unclear whether NCR 7199 supports it, ESC/POS has the ability to customize the font of the user-defined code page rather than the individual characters.
Please refer to the contents of the following pages.

[GS ( E <Function 7>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=235)

> Copy the user-defined page

[GS ( E <Function 8>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=236)

> Define the data (column format) for the character code page

[GS ( E <Function 9>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=237)

> Define the data (raster format) for the character code page

[GS ( E <Function 10>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=238)

> Delete the data for the character code page

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I took a closer look at these functions. It's a bit complicated to define whole code page while we need to override only 2 symbols. So we decided to turn on user-defined characters (ESC % 1) before printing special symbols, and turn off (ESC % 0) after that. Not graceful, but easier to implement.

Comment: Anyway I checked the functions on NCR 7199. The printer seems to be unable to recognize Function 8: it prints symbols, defined in the command (c1 c2)